# Alpaca form: loading schema and options from .json file

Tags: javascript, forms, alpacajs

I'm trying to use Alpaca to generate a configurable form. 
I would like to do as showed here: http://www.alpacajs.org/demos/bootstrap/customer-profile/create-simple-form.html (load options and schema from json file). 
I wrote the following simple code:

```
    <body>
     <div id="form"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#form").alpaca({
                 "schemaSource": "path_to_my_schema/schema.json"
             });
         });
     </script>
 </body>
```

It looks super simple but it is not working...I would appreciate any help!

Comment: What isn't working exaclty, do you get errors in the console? Are you sure the dependencies are loaded? Does it work if you test it with the script on the alpaca homepage? (with just a schema hard-coded, not loading from file)

Comment: It works when I test with the hard-coded schema.
When I try the other way, my form does'nt show in the browser and I have erros in the console : {"message":"Unable to load data from uri : /path_to_my_schema/schema.json","stage":"DATA_LOADING_ERROR","details":{"jqXHR":{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"error"},"textStatus":"error","errorThrown":""}

My schema.json file is the exact copy of what can be found here: alpacajs.org/demos/bootstrap/customer-profile/schema.json If I use the url to the file instead of "pathtomyschema" it works fine

Comment: hm, and you're sure the path is right? it looks like it just can't find it.

Comment: like, if it's in the same directory, just "./schema.json" should do it

Comment: It works just with "schema.json" if in the same directory. I must have gotten mixed up, sorry about that... And thank you for your time!

Comment: No problem!  Would you mind accepting the answer as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the same directory, just "./schema.json" should do it.